# Показать отделы в которых НЕ работают люди в контексте предиката EXISTS

Tags: sql

Show departments which have not employees - показать отделы в которых не работают люди(их там нет) - вот само задание, но его суть в том, что запрос нужно написать в "слепую" не имея CTE и таблицы с нужными данными. Вот мой код

```
SELECT workdept
FROM employee a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee b WHERE b.workdept = a.workdept)
```

Он не до конца правильный, что в нем нужно поправить.
И в реальной таблице если "имени" нет - значением будет null?

Comment: `select * from department d where not exists (select 1 from employee e where e.department_uid = d.uid)`

Comment: @nörbörnën т.е. в равенстве должно быть отдел=имя? что то пока не совсем понимаю